# Validate XML with XSD issue

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this simple XML:

```
<company>
<departments>
    <department IDDepartment="A01" director="00001234S">
        <employee PassportNumber="00001234S">
            <name>Daniel</name>
            <lastname>Robinson Harris</lastname>
            <salary>2100.86</salary>
        </employee>
        <employee PassportNumber="79300210A">
            <name>Lara</name>
            <lastname>Williams</lastname>
            <salary>1100</salary>
        </employee>
    </department>
    <department IDDepartment="A02" director="09448822T">
        <employee PassportNumber="12345678A">
            <name>Daniel</name>
            <lastname>Brown</lastname>
            <salary>1200</salary>
        </employee>
        <employee PassportNumber="09448822T">
            <name>Tom</name>
            <lastname>Johnson Smith</lastname>
            <salary>2500.50</salary>
        </employee>
    </department>
</departments>
```

I want to validate with XSD that the "director" value corresponds to the passport number of one of the employees.
I'm new to XSD and I'm trying to figure out how to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: It is possible just with XSD 1.1

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Comment: When you say "one of the employees" do you mean one of the employees in the same department?

Comment: @MichaelKay No, from any department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have XSD 1.1 you can probably do this with key/keyref.

On the `department` element, define a key with `selector="."`, `field="@director"`, and a corresponding `keyref` with `selector="employee"`, `field="@PassportNumber"`.

*UPDATE*

With the additional information that it can be an employee in a different department, the key needs to be defined as follows:

On the `departments` element, define a key with `selector="department"`, `field="@director"`, and a corresponding `keyref` with `selector=".//employee"`, `field="@PassportNumber"`.

Comment: What if more than one `<employee>` has the same **PassportNumber** within the same department?

Comment: Indeed. Writing a schema based on one example of a valid document is always going to involve a lot of guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use XSD 1.1.

It has an `assert` functionality to validate business rules.

XSD processors **Saxon**, **Xerces**, and some others are conformant with the XSD 1.1

The XSD below is using Xerces 2.12.2 for tailored validation messages.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <departments>
        <department IDDepartment="A01" director="00001234S">
            <employee PassportNumber="00001234S">
                <name>Daniel</name>
                <lastname>Robinson Harris</lastname>
                <salary>2100.86</salary>
            </employee>
            <employee PassportNumber="79300210A">
                <name>Lara</name>
                <lastname>Williams</lastname>
                <salary>1100</salary>
            </employee>
        </department>
        <department IDDepartment="A02" director="09448822T">
            <employee PassportNumber="12345678A">
                <name>Daniel</name>
                <lastname>Brown</lastname>
                <salary>1200</salary>
            </employee>
            <employee PassportNumber="09448822T">
                <name>Tom</name>
                <lastname>Johnson Smith</lastname>
                <salary>2500.50</salary>
            </employee>
        </department>
    </departments>
</company>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="company">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="departments"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="departments">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="department"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="department">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="employee"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="IDDepartment" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="director" use="required" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:assert test="count(employee[@PassportNumber=../@director])=1" xerces:message="Department's director value shall correspond to the passport number of one of the employees">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Rule #: 28-34</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation>Department's director value shall correspond to the passport number of one of the employees</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:assert>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="employee">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="name"/>
                <xs:element ref="lastname"/>
                <xs:element ref="salary"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="PassportNumber" use="required" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="salary" type="xs:decimal"/>
</xs:schema>
```